# snapd service keeps disabling itself

Tags: services, daemon, systemctl, snap

I'm trying to install snapd using snap `sudo snap install snapd`, but i get the following error.

`error: cannot communicate with server: Post "http://localhost/v2/snaps/snapd": dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: connection refused`

I have tried enabling the snapd service several times and when i run `systemctl status snapd` this is what i get.

```
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/snapd.service; enabled; preset: disabled)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Thu 2023-03-30 11:16:08 EDT; 5min ago
   Duration: 5.012s
TriggeredBy: ● snapd.socket
    Process: 42619 ExecStart=/usr/lib/snapd/snapd (code=exited, status=42)
   Main PID: 42619 (code=exited, status=42)
        CPU: 77ms
```

it shows that its been inactive since 5 minutes ago, which was the last time that i ran `sudo systemctl start snapd.service`. I can't figure out why its inactive, I have also run `sudo systemctl enable snapd.service` to create the symlink and i can't download anything from snap right now. I get the following error

```
error: cannot communicate with server: Post "http://localhost/v2/snaps/snapd": dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: no such file or directory
```

obviously the daemon isn't active, but i can't figure out how to keep it running without going inactive immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try running `sudo systemctl enable snapd.apparmor`

apparently after reading some error logs the snapd service is likely failing because snapd.apparmor wasn't enabled

Hope this helps!